# how to change background color of dynamically added ifram on click of iFrame in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to change iframe background color on click of iframe; and this iframe added through append.

```
var frame = '<div class="append-div"><iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="iFrameClass" style="background-color: #ff0000;"></iframe></div>';


$('div.post-body').find('img:eq(0)').closest('.iframe-div').append(frame);

$('div.post-body').find('img:eq(1)').closest('.iframe-div').append(frame);  

$(document).on('click','.iFrameClass',function() {
    alert();
    $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    // $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color','blue');
});
```

Thank you,

Comment: Are you trying to change the `background-color` of the content of the iframe?

Comment: yes, Please help me

Comment: Not sure about same-origin sources, but you definitely can't do it if the source is on another domain - That will be a security risk

Comment: @AlonEitan: I just want change Iframe Background color, how to do?

Comment: I don't think that you can - But maybe someone else will prove me wrong

Comment: @AlonEitan: I got solution, thank you, Please check it is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // alert()
    var frame = '<div class="append-div"><iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="iFrameClass" style="background-color: #ff0000;"></iframe></div>';

$('div.post-body').find('img:eq(0)').closest('.iframe-div').append(frame);

$('div.post-body').find('img:eq(1)').closest('.iframe-div').append(frame);  

$('iframe').contents().find('body').on('click',$('iframe').contents().find('body'),function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','blue');
});

});
```

Thank you,
For your help